# Delete lots of rows from a very large Cassandra Table

Tags: cassandra

I have a table Foo with 4 columns A, B, C, D. The partitioning key is A. The clustering key is B, C, D.

I want to scan the entire table and find all rows where D is in set (X, Y, Z).

Then I want to delete these rows but I don't want to "kill" Cassandra (because of compactions), I'd like these rows deleted with minimal disruption or risk.

How can I do this?

Comment: Might wanna check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhGkSnBZgJA for a deleting compaction strategy, not part of C* OSS directly but may solve issue without requiring all the reads. https://github.com/protectwise/cassandra-util/tree/master/deleting-compaction-strategy

Comment: Hi Chris Lohfink, do you know an equivalent solution that works with a recent version of Cassandra (3 or 4) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a big problem here. Indeed, you really can't find the rows without actually scanning all of your partitions. The problem real problem is that C* will allow you to restrict your queries with a partition key, and then by your cluster keys in the order in which they appear in your `PRIMARY KEY` table declaration. So if your PK is like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY (A, B, C, D)
```

then you'd need to filter by A first, then by B, C, and only at the end by D.

That being said, for the part of **finding your rows**, if this is something you have to run only once, you

1. Could scan all your table and do comparisons of D in your App logic.
2. If you know the values of A you could query every partition in parallel and then compare D in your application
3. You could attach a secondary index and try to exploit speed from there.

Please note that depending on how many nodes do you have 3 is really not an option, secondary indexes don't scale)

If you need to perform such tasks multiple times, I'd suggest you to create another table that would satisfy this query, something like `PRIMARY KEY (D)`, you'd then just scan three partitions and that would be very fast.

About **deleting your rows**, I think there's no way to do it without triggering compactions, they are part of C* and you have to live with them. If you really can't tolerate tombstone creation and/or compactions, the only alternative is to **not** delete rows from a C* cluster, and that often means thinking about a new data model that won't need deletes.

Comment: I don't have to do this multiple times. this is part of a one time cleanup. May be its more optimal for me to just create another table and then move the filtered data there and delete the original table. I have heard from my admins that "too much" tombstone creation is very problematic for them.

Comment: You should then take advantage of the situation, and *denormalize* all your data by creating multiple tables suited to satisfy *all* the queries you need to perform. It would be a huge win.